# Where should I upload the built file of a github branch?

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a github project and while I'm developing I want to provide all builds I make to my users. For this I not only tag/snapshot the branch but I also want to provide the already compiled version of my program but I haven't found a good place to upload it to.

I have seen that some people upload those to a special branch but somehow that seems a bit weird to me because that wouldn't be a real *branch* in the original sense.

Is it bad style to do this or am I just too picky? Can someone propose an alternate way/website that fits my needs and is possibly closely connected to github?

Comment: See https://help.github.com/categories/85/articles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub has **releases** that you can associate to tags (see "[Creating Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases)"):

- no need for a special branch
- tag your code
- upload the corresponding binary to the release associated to that tag

See more on "[About Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases)"

Comment: That sure is a really nice feature (I didn't know of)! Does code.google or bitbucket have this sort of feature aswell?

Comment: @WorldSEnder I don't think so.